# How to set background color of toolbar in windows phone using xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.windows

I want to set the background color of the application bar blue.how can i do it in xamarin.forms? Do I have to write the native code for the same how to do that?

Comment: Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641348/xamarin-forms-actionbar-color)?

Comment: You should probably show the code of your form

Comment: @ventiseis yes i have checked that but that was not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer  of my question myself.
In the native windows phone 8.1 app in `MainPage.xaml` write the following code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Background="#0073b5" Foreground="White">

    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Isn't there something missing?

Comment: complete code has not appeared its  <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Background="#0073b5" Foreground="White">